# My wordpress site redirects me to dummy website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

When I search keyword on google and click on my site it redirects to some dummy url. Can any one please help me to fix it out. If I go through on that url by my website then it's working fine it's only redirects to dummy website if I go through google search.

Comment: Look at your .htaccess file. It has likely been hacked: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136167/how-to-restore-google-search-results-after-a-hack

Comment: [More here](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+hacked+wordpress+google+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: I have scanned whole project and uploaded on live but it's still not working

Comment: With dummy content are you referring to demo content ? if this is the case, you have to start by either removing the dummy content or change it to draft status. after all pages that should not be indexed are either removed or changed to draft you can follow the instructions in this [google article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) to remove them from search results